# Generate PDF file of html in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pdf-generation

I have a customer detail form page in which customer will enter his/her detail and click submit button.
After clicking, data is submitting in mongodb using node.js. Now I want to generate the PDF file of the entered data at the same time when click on submit button.

Can anyone suggest me how to generate PDF file when click on button.

Comment: Use command 'window.print()'

Comment: I am not asking for print the page... I want to generate pdf file in just a click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PDFKit](https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit) if you want to make your own formatting or [node-html-pdf](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf) if you just need to convert your HTML into PDF

Comment: please check my code , Its not working router.post('/create', function(req, res, next){
 var PDFDocument=require('pdfkit');
var doc=new PDFDocument();
var path=require('./public/pdf');
var filename=req.body.filename;
var content=req.body.content;
doc.y=320;
doc.text(content, 100, 100);
doc.write(path.resolve('.')+'/PDF/'+filename+'.pdf');
res.download(path.resolve('.')+'/PDF/'+filename+'.pdf');
doc.end();
 
 });

Comment: Did you try to run example from GitHub? What is `require('./public/pdf');`? Use `createWriteStream` instead of `write`. Keep in mind, that it is async operation and you must wait while it finished. Also you should finalize PDF before sending it to client with `res.download`

Comment: Now I am writing this- `var PDF = require('pdfkit'); 
var fs = require('fs');
var text = 'Candidate Name:'+req.body.filename;
doc = new PDF();                        
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('filee.pdf'));  
doc.text(text, 20, 20);  
doc.end(); ` pdf is creating successfully. now problem is that when I create again and again the pdf is overwriting with previous one.  any solution?

Comment: Write files with different names. And I think it would be better if you will write them into specific directory